# Windows 7: Screen recording is laggy

Tags: windows-7, windows, screen-capture, hdvideo

I want to make a video of a shooter game in 720p *HD* format in Windows 7. But the video is always laggy (low *fps*). I'm using *Camtasia Studio*.
If capture area (resolution) is smaller, the *fps* is OK, but I can't say it's good...

What I've tried:

- remove all special effects in Windows
- set the theme to Classic (not *Aero*)
- remove all special effects in the game
- change recording codec settings

But the video is still bad.
My PC is rather good. I think it is *Windows 7*'s fault...

What else can I do to improve the screen recording performance?

Comment: Have you tried other software that includes video capture functionality, like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) or [XFire](http://www.xfire.com/)?  I mean, just to rule out the possibility that the capture software is the problem.

Comment: Camtasia is for full desktop recording, while Fraps and XFire actually hook into the game and record frames in-game.

Comment: It seems like FRAPS is actually faster. I think I will have to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you tried other software that includes video capture functionality, like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) or [XFire](http://www.xfire.com/)? I mean, just to rule out the possibility that the capture software is the problem.
>   – [boot13](https://superuser.com/users/41423/boot13)

---

> Camtasia is for full desktop recording, while Fraps and XFire actually hook into the game and record frames in-game.
>   – [Corey](https://superuser.com/users/11510/corey)

Answer (score 1):

You could set up Camtasia Recorder to use the DivX codec instead of the TSCC codec, and if you have a nice fast CPU (3ghz+) plus a lot of RAM you may be OK.

Another option might be using two computers and a remote desktop.  That way Camtasia Studio is not running on the same system as the game so you aren't sharing the CPU resources.

Does the game you are playing need hardware acceleration? If not, you could try turning down hardware acceleration to help improve video quality.

If all else fails, contact TechSmith for free tech support by phone (+1.517.381.2300) or http://techsmith.custhelp.com/.

Comment: I'm using *DivX ;-) MPEG-4 Fast-Motion* codec, but that doesn't help. Other DivX codecs just crash the *Recorder*